# Hyperledger data persistence between fabric restarts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have tried to search and research on this topic, but could not find any solution so far.

Has anyone tried this scenario? Start the fabric, create a business network, create a sample app to post transactions to this network. So far so good. Shut down the fabric now and restart it. Has anyone seen that the transactions are lost? So how does one go about making the ledger survive restarts?

Comment: @david_k : Thank you! Thank you! Yes it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You need to mount a volume for the directory `/var/hyperledger/production` in the orderer and peer containers in docker. This is where all the persistent data is being held containing channel information, transactions and blocks.

If you are spinning up your containers through docker-compose you can add:

```
volumes:
  - <some local dir>:/var/hyperledger/production
```

If you are spinning up your containers through docker run add the argument:

```
-v <some local dir>:/var/hyperledger/production
```

Haven't used composer much myself so not quite sure how composer builds the containers, if you are using that.

You will also need to make sure each node goes to its own directory so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: i have user some local directory but when i restart the network and try to invoke any chaincode function the orderer container is exiting.